# sending HTML template crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, html-email

I'm trying to do e-mail campaing with HTML template inside e-mail.
But I have issue with that. 
I've decided to make template with table, which has 3 rows and inside middle row I made one more table for text. 
But when I sending e-mail with that template, it looks not as it should in Gmail and other mail clients. But in Outlook it looks good as it should.

MS CRM separate my HTML code on div's. Every TAG CRM include in div. 
But if send one massage it works good.

Comment: Is this a code issue or a CRM software issue converting your previously correct html? If it is the first, please post some code. If it is the second, this is probably the wrong forum for software specific questions.

Comment: that issue  doesn't with code. Problem with CRM for sure. 
This forum is the last destination)))